# Iterate through a List of Strings starting from 'One' String until 'Another' String in Java

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to iterate through a List of Strings in Java.
My List consists of:

```
["DataFileDownload/FD/722066/71493/2016/12/30/untitled-1.aux","DataFileDownload/FD/722066/71493/2016/12/31/untitled-2.aux","DataFileDownload/FD/722066/71493/2017/01/01/untitled-3.aux","DataFileDownload/FD/722066/71493/2016/01/02/untitled-4.aux"]
```

And I am reading the dates from the user as:

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date fromDate = fmt.parse("2016-12-30");
Date toDate = fmt.parse("2017-01-02");
Calendar fromCal = Calendar.getInstance();
fromCal.setTime(fromDate);
String fromYear = String.valueOf(fromCal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
String fromMonth = String.valueOf(fromCal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1);
String fromDay = String.valueOf(fromCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
Calendar toCal = Calendar.getInstance();
toCal.setTime(toDate);
String toYear = String.valueOf(toCal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
String toMonth = String.valueOf(toCal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1);
String toDay = String.valueOf(toCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

If I wanted to extract the Strings from date: 30-dec-2016 to 01-Jan-2017, i.e.

```
"DataFileDownload/FD/722066/71493/2016/12/30/untitled-1.aux","DataFileDownload/FD/722066/71493/2016/12/31/untitled-2.aux","DataFileDownload/FD/722066/71493/2017/01/01/untitled-3.aux"
```

I'm using the below loop:-

```
for(String s : NameList){
    if((s.equals(fromYear) && s.equals(fromMonth) && s.equals(fromDay)) == true){
  while((s.equals(toYear) && s.equals(toMonth) && s.equals(toDay)) != true){
     System.out.println(s);
  }
  System.out.println(s);
}
```

I get no result.

But when I try this:

```
       for(String s : objectNameList){
           if((s.contains(fromYear) && s.contains(fromMonth) && s.contains(fromDay))){
               System.out.println(s);
           }
       }
```

I get only:

```
"DataFileDownload/FD/722066/71493/2016/12/30/untitled-1.aux"
```

Can anyone please let me know how can I improve my loop condition?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Java is not an acronym.

Comment: You are trying to equate your string value to multiple different values and also would you really expect `"DataFileDownload/FD/722066/71493/2016/12/30/untitled-1.aux"` to equal `String.valueOf(fromCal.get(Calendar.YEAR));`. Use either a contains but for more reliability you will need to parse your input String.

Comment: You need to parse the string and remove those != true and == true, equals return Boolean. As Java Devil said, you need to extract date from the string and then compare

Comment: @shmosel thanks for reminding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go string by string in your list and extract the date using regular expression, something like this:

```
private static String getDate(String str) {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\.*(?<date>([0-9]{4}\\/[0-9]{2}\\/[0-9]{2}))");
    Matcher matcher = regex.matcher(str);
    boolean success = matcher.find();
    return (success ? matcher.group("date") : null);
}

// Example:
String dateStr = getDate("DataFileDownload/FD/722066/71493/2016/12/30/untitled-1.aux");
```

Save it as a `Date` object:

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
Date date = fmt.parse(dateStr);
```

Then, read the input dates from the user and save them as `Date` objects.

Then, you can compare the user dates and the dates from the list using:

```
java.util.Date.before(Date when);
java.util.Date.after(Date when);
```

Much easier than parsing all the dates and playing with strings.

Comment: Hi @SHG, thanks for the solution, I'm able to get extract the dates from the string.

Comment: but when I print `date` I get: `Fri Dec 30 00:00:00 IST 2016`. Hence, it is not comparing when I use the loop: `for(String s : objectNameList){
                if(date.after(fromDate)){
                       if(date.before(toDate)){
                        finalObjectNames.add(s);
                       }
               }
               }`

Comment: @ChetanHireholi `Date` is a Java container for a date. It's not responsible for the format when you print it. To format it you use `DateFormatter` like: `System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(theDateObject));`

Comment: @ChetanHireholi It is comparing - for the comparison, you're using the dates *objects* (not their string representation) which is exactly the right way.

Comment: thanks, I looked it up too. But why I'm failing in the loop?

Comment: FYI, `fromDate` and `toDate` are both `Date` objects

Comment: @ChetanHireholi Are you updating the variable `date` each iteration according to the current `s` in the loop? Each iteration you need to call `getDate(s)` and then update `date` accordingly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146128/discussion-between-chetan-hireholi-and-shg).

Answer (score 1):

Convert the date values from String to Integer.

```
 int fromYear=Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(fromCal.get(Calendar.YEAR)));
 int fromMonth=Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(fromCal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1));
 int fromDay = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(fromCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));

 int toYear = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(toCal.get(Calendar.YEAR)));
 int toMonth = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(toCal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1));
 int toDay =   Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(toCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
```

Then split the Sting List and get year, month, day from the string inside the for block

```
 String[] f = s.split("/");      
 int year1 = Integer.parseInt(f[4]);
 int month1 = Integer.parseInt(f[5]);
 int day1 = Integer.parseInt(f[6]);
```

Then apply the logic to match date in between from date and to date

```
            if((fromYear <  year1) && (toYear >  year1))
                    {
                            System.out.println(s);  
                    }
                    else if((fromYear ==  year1))
                    {
                            if((fromMonth <=  month1) && (fromDay >= day1))
                            {
                                    System.out.println(s);
                            }
                    }
                    else if((toYear ==  year1))
                    {
                            if((toMonth >=  month1) || (toDay == day1))
                            {
                                    System.out.println(s);
                            }
                    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution man. But spliting the string might be a little risky, since any change in the string in the List might alter the result. For this I'll have to modify the `Integer.parseInt(f[*])` again and again for doing changes